# how do you insert a swf file with collada interactivity within it into an html page?

Tags: html, flash, collada

I have a swf file which I need embedded into a webpage.  Does safari and google chrome support swf files with collada in it?

Comment: What is supported inside a SWF file depends on the Flash player, not the browser, doesn't it? Just follow the basic instructions on how to embed SWF into a HTML page, I assume

Comment: only the background image shows though.  I can't see the collada image when I put it in the html file.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got it working. Schoolboy error.  I needed to put the html code from the html file made from the swf file into another webpage and keep all other contents in the same folder.  Phew  :)